# Differentiate QRCode and QRCode's Screenshot / Image using QRCode Reader

Tags: java, android, swift, kotlin, swift5

I am using **QRCodeReaderView** library to scan a QRCode. Everything is working perfect like reading QRCode and getting values.

I did the majors to avoid things such as capturing or screenshooting a QRCode, but there's still a thread that one can take a QRCode's picture from some other mobile device and can use that picture to scan the QRCode.

Is there any chance that while scanning from QRCode Reader / Scanner, I can detect that the QRCode displayed is not a true QRCode but an image of QRCode taken from some other device.

How can I differentiate between ?

**P.S**: As I described above, everything works perfectly, that's why I don't share any code, and what I need here is that if yes then how can I distinguish..

**P.S** I need some expert on this please.. I just came across a Project In which there was a face detection scenario, the system was able to distinguish between the real face of a person and the picture of that person.. They were the winners in a competition..[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of the images that you want to distinguish between? i.e. one image that shows a "true QRCode" (whatever that means) and another image that shows a non-"true QRCode".

Comment: @Sweeper I am scanning a simple QR generated by QR Code Generator and its in my android activity's layout and scanning it by using QrCodeReader.. It work perfect if i show my phone which has this QRCode in front of a tablet which has the QRCodeReader

What I want to prevent is if any one takes a picture of my QRCode layout from some other device and show it to Tablet, I should be able to identify that this is a picture

Comment: But can you tell me how are the two cases different on a physical level? We can't solve this problem without know that, right? This is why I asked for _images_.

Comment: There are no two separate pictures, there is a device in which you have an app and you open it I have a QRCode in there if I show the device to tablet it should work fine, BUT if i take a picture from other phone and then show that picture to tablet I want to stop that

Comment: Ask yourself this: How can you, as a human, identify "take a picture from other phone and then show that picture to tablet"?

Comment: I never said it was impossible. I am saying that your question is unclear. You are unclear on whether it is the "screenshot" refers to a screenshot of a QR code, or a photo of another device, which displays a QR Code. This is why I asked for _two_ images: one showing an example of an image you want to _accept_, the other showing an example of an image you want to _reject_.

Comment: I have no idea if what you're asking is feasible, but it may be simpler to just try to introduce some kind of [time based component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_algorithm) with a short interval, so that you give very little time for anyone to try to steal a QR-code and use it themselves.

Comment: @Michael I guess you get what I ask for, short intervals can be applied but it will be a load on the system because it will became a pool which will get execute every X seconds

Comment: @Sweeper lets see this with a different angle, lets talk about layout showing on mobile call it 'real one' and take the picture from other device of this call it 'not real'
If I show 'real one' to tablet having QRCode scanner it should allow it and if we show 'not real' it should say please don't try to CHEAT

Comment: Are you asking for any possible technology/SDK/libs to differentiate pics with real face? Or do you want to create such library and seeking for logical advice?

Answer (score 2):

There’s a difference in distinguishing between a persons face and a photo of a persons face. And a QR code compared to a screenshot of said QR code’s. Heck, due to something known as the [Reed Solomon Method algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction) a QR code can still be scanned if it’s partially obscured (to an extent)

If multiple instances are your worry, the only thing you can do is have unique QR code’s for every person with a unique ID assigned to them. There’s no way to distinguish between a QR code and a photo of one. That’s just how it is

Comment: It means there is a loophole then in the implementation of QR Code, because any time one can take a pic of QRCode from other device and can use that pic to scan..

"you can do is have unique QR code’s for every person with a unique ID assigned to them".. I have already done this

Comment: that  is true, unfortunately this is a side effect of the customization an accessibility of QR codes. They are designed to be convenient, not secure. The only way you can implement security is have each user receive a separate QR code tied to an ID number and allow it to only be used once.or perhaps the QR code takes you to a login page. That's really all you can do, sorry :/

Comment: Its just how QR code's are designed. They are insecure, and personally i try to avoid them. I have a decent experience with QR codes and more specifically cyber security, and this is just something you have to deal with. Either you pick a different method? or you accept the flaws with QR codes. Nothing you can do about it and that's just a fact

Comment: This doesn't answer my requirements, some questions need customized answers
what your answer told is just repeating the standards, and everyone know those standards
I was expecting some customized answer..

Comment: @SyedNazarMuhammad I’m sorry that you feel that way,I wasn’t trying to just give a vague answer, it’s just unfortunately what you wanted cannot he accomplished, I’m sorry :( I wish you good luck on finding an alternative solution

Comment: I am not good at Matlab or machine learning stuff, else I think it could be done using those techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should rethink your approach.

Your statement *I did the majors to avoid things such as capturing or screenshooting a QRCode* already implies the system you are tying to build is not secure.

If you're trying to build something secure the approach you should use is using a system which is built from scratch with security in mind and NOT take any (insecure) system and try to fix it's insecurities to make it (pseudo-)secure.
Trying to make an insecure system secure by securing some edge cases will **never** secure your system. There will always be people who will find another edge case to exploit your system.

Here are multiple cases how your system can be exploited even if you try to secure it by recognizing if it's a real QR-code or a picture of it:

- Use an external app (like Az-screen recorder), record a video of the screen and then extract an image with the QR code from the video. Showing it on another phone will always look original.
- Take a photo of the QR-code, you can now create a QR-code from scratch by setting each black/white pixel by hand in an image creation software or similar. Showing this on another phone will, again, look like a real QR code.

As you can see there are multiple cases how your system can be exploited and especially you can't fix the last point.

So even if you manage to detect if the camera is pointed to a real QR-code or a photograph of it (which is also hard to impossible, see answer by @ItsMeNaira) your system will not be secure, as you can't make an insecure system secure by fixing it's edge cases.

Again: **Never** try to secure a system which was not created with security in mind by fixing corner cases, you will **always** fail. Instead try to find a better approach, which is built with security in mind from scratch.

Comment: I do not agree, I think there are many use cases where you need to make compromises between security and ease of use. and you always need to asses the the magnitude of the incentive for fraud. for example I understand that my bank uses 2 or even 3 factor validation but this is not practical for a system designed to control access to some random facility or a voucher discount system. If I did that noone would use my vouchers plus noone is going to invest excesive effort in hacking a voucher system that will maybe give them only a few $ of discount

Comment: I agree with you, there are use cases where you need to compromise between security and usability and I don't think this is a contradiction to my answer. Your answer describes adding a new layer of security which is totally fine, to make a system more secure in total. What Syed tried to do instead is to fix one single corner case of a system which is not secure at all and this kind of pseudo-security should be definitely avoided

Comment: Let's take HTTP for example, which is insecure by default. SSL/TLS is an extra added layer of security to make the system/protocol [more] secure (totally fine). But it does not try to fix single insecurities of HTTP.

Comment: you are right there, you could see what I did as an additional layer

Answer (score 1):

What @ItsMeNaira said is completely right, there in no way of knowing if a QR code is the real deal or a picture, but in my opinion there are some things you can still do. some more simple that others.

I build an app for access control, my QR code is an access key for the users of a gym. I simply show a picture of the user whenever he registers with the QR code at the entrance of the gym. you can fake a QR code but you cant fake your face. admittedly you still need a person controlling entries (or the illusion of one;)) for this to work but it solves the problem of authenticity in a simple analogous way. In my opinion you should try and couple your QR code with some sort of alternative validation. often the simple illusion of being watched or that ones transgressions can be tracked back suffices to discourage fraud.

an alternative approach if the users of your QR code are using an app to generate the QR code is to have both devices (i.e. the one that currently generates the QR code and the one that currently scans the QR code) scan each other as a means to validate each scan. this would mean having 1 QR-codes and 1 scanner on each device. the first code would be generated randomly and the second would be a function of the first one. I briefly thought about this approach but didnt implement it and you would have to test and see how user friendly it is. but it would allow you to ensure your QR code comes from a valid device using your app.

In order to be able to better ideate a solution it would be helpful to understand your application better. What are the codes for? why would the user commit fraud? in which setting is he using the app?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, I feel like using basic image processing would be a good way to go about it. The case for which a screenshot (high resolution image, directly from the device), the image processing would be able to see that the amount of noise in the image is little to none. However, with the picture of a display - especially lower resolution ones - when a picture of a display is taken, the camera captures all of the RGB lights from the screen - making white look like a mix between all of the aforementioned colours.

TL;DR - My suggestion would be that because of the fact that the pictures taken of a display would make the image quite noisy - using a basic image processing tool would differentiate between a screenshot and a picture of a display.

I hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;** There is a possible work around, but you would have to extend QRCodeReaderView class and use some image processing.

Though you cannot directly distinguish within the QRCode reader library itself, you could use some hidden pixels that are only visible via image processing. This is the approach that was used in the Shazam app's "image recognition" functionality. To implement you would have a QR code that is only visible to the device when a "filter" is applied. In essence it's a picture hidden within a picture.

In this instance you would have 2 QR codes laid atop each other. One that is visible to the naked eye or generic camera, and a second QR code that is visible after doing some image processing. In your QR code scanner you would  apply the image filters and send the processed image to the QR reader method.

This would protect against photographs, because most camera apps would not pick up on the "hidden" pixels.